# Length of INT in C++

Tags: c++, integer

Is there a way for me to limit the number of characters of int in C++? I'm kind of new to this language. Hope I could get some answers from you, guys! Thank you!

Comment: What's "the number of characters of int"? Could you elaborate or give an example?

Comment: There is `int16_t` and `int8_t`, but until we know what you really want, we're only guessing. Also, could you tell us which language(s) you're familiar with?

Comment: Like for example, in char, i could specify its length by typing char[4]. What if I want to limit the number of int inputs to 4 characters only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [size of int, long, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about number of bits, you can use, [short](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keywords/short), [char](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keywords/char) instead of int. You can see int8_t, etc in [c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit how many characters a user can input as an int, you can use a control-structure checking if the entered value is between 2 limits.
ex: if you want to limit a user to entering 2 char's, you can limit the input between -10 & 100

Limiting the size of the number (in bits) can be done by using a smaller type (smaller range).
byte < sbyte < ushort < short < uint < int < ...

Answer (score 0):

`char[4]` defines an array of chars. You're not limiting the size of a `char` itself, but declaring an automatic-storage fixed-length array.

And sure, you can create `int` arrays in the same fashion: `int[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

if we use while loop like this code , We will make counter (n) is Increasing unless X=0 because of that condition will became (false),So will printed (n)

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x(1), n(0);
    while(x){
    //cout << x << endl;
    n++;
    x/=10;
    }
    cout << n;
    
}
```